# How to change jquery datatable value by dropdown value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jquery datatable to display table data based on dropdown list value, I am using ajax to get data from the table.

The problem is when the table first loads it is working fine but when I click on sort or search it displays processing which does not change until i refresh the page,the code is given below:

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {


                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    //"bProcessing": true,
                    //"sAjaxSource": "response.php",

                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    //"bDestroy": true,
//                "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { mData: 'FNAME' } ,
                        { mData: 'FPRICE' },
                        { mData: 'IMGPATH' },
                        { mData: 'FDESC' },
                        { mData: 'CID' }
                    ],



                    "ajax": {
                        'type': 'POST',
                        'url': 'response.php',
                        'data': {id: $('#myselect').val()}
//                    "success":function (res) {
//
//                    }
                    }

                });

            $('#myselect').change(function() {
                var item = $(this).val();
                // alert(item)
                var urld = 'response.php/'+item;
                table.ajax.url(urld).load();
                table.reload();

            });

//            setInterval( function () {
//                table.ajax.reload();
//            }, 10000 );

                //table.fnDraw();





        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using serverside processing check this out for custom sort https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9857/server-side-processing-custom-sort-solution-like-formatted-num-sorting-plug-in